# How to match dangling blobs with file names in Git?

Tags: git, blobs, git-dangling

I have yet another example of doing a `git rm -rf` without an initial commit. (I realized I had added lots of useless files and wanted to add some filters.)

Now I am left with 23000 dangling blobs with no tree, but with a complete Git history!

I'll use a script to loop over the blobnames (using `git show 'blobname' > 'filename'`), but can I associate these filenames from the history to the blobs?

Comment: hmm, I originally thought you typed `rm -rf`.  You can still get it back, you need to find the root tree object.

Comment: check the type of those objects - are the ALL blobs?? or is there a tree in there anywhere? Either way you can do `git cat-file <blob>` to see what it contains for comparison. Also have a look at their date stamps in case that gives you a clue.

Comment: @Alex: how do I find the root tree object? is that in one of the blobs?

Comment: @Philip: indeed, they all are blobs. I can use `git cat-file`, but to compare with what? I only have the list of filenames.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you've got real problems. I hadn't realised that `git add` didn't create a local tree but waited till the commit for that, leaving details in the index. Unfortunately the 'git rm` clears all that from the index. I guess its time to triage the blobs into bin, ascii and utf8, to try to reduce the list size - 23,000 is a lot of crud.

Answer (score 2):

For all of you who did/will do the exact mistake I made, here's the end of the story.

First off, a brief summary of what I did.

1. Created an empty repository
2. moved many files/directory to it
3. `gid add .`
4. realized that I just added a TON of useless/not-so-important/redundant files
5. `git rm -rf`  with the intent of then adding some filters in .gitignore
6. realized that all my files were gone...

I tried all sort of data recovery tools; no luck.
The best I could do was the following procedure.

1. Immediately copy the working directory to a different volume
   (external HD).
2. `git fsck --lost-found`    possibly with `--unreachable --cache`
       This creates the folder `.git/lost-found/other` with all (most of?)
       the original files were re-created, but without filenames. Now the problem was 
   how to recover the file names. Unfortunately, all the files I recovered were blobs, no roots, so I had no information about the tree structure of the directories.
3. Even though I had the complete list of lost filenames (only names, not sizes), I could not find any root, so this information was basically useless.
4. In general, one can write a script that uses `file` to look at the type of a file (`file <filename>`), and attaches the corresponding extension to it. The problem of matching files with filenames still remains.
   Alternatively, one can use brute force. For instance, to recover pdfs, I sorted the recovered files by length, attached a .pdf extension to them, and looked at them one by one. The files that were actual pdfs show something, the others don't.
5. To recover text-based files (txt, tex, c, h..), I used grep, looking for a string that I remember belongs to a specific (group of) file(s).
6. Now I keep the directory with all the lost-recovered files, and every time I need one of them, I use a slight variant of bullet 4.

Good luck!