# git -add then git -rm -r deleted entire project before commit

Tags: git, version-control

I'm on Windows 10, new to git.  Lost my project before committing. I used git commands in this order (project name is DeltaSearch located in c:/git/dev/utils/DeltaSearch with c:/git/dev being the repository root).

```
git add DeltaSearch/*
```

added too many files , then tried to start over

```
git rm Deltasearch/* -r -f
```

Entire project was deleted from the SSD. I've tried:

```
git reset -HEAD
```

It's still gone.  Also tried:

```
git stash

git stash drop
```

Still gone.  Afraid to try any other commands unless someone knows if this is fixable. Thank you.

Comment: I hate that response "should have read this."  You can say that to everyone on StackOverflow!  Your comment doesn't really help me.  Yes, I've read plenty of git tutorials already.  I'm looking for expert advice in this situation.

Comment: You should've used the `--cached` option. Without it, it actually deletes the files instead of just removing them. If it wasn't committed and/or pushed, you likely can't recover it. And if you're just untracking it, that's a separate option. And you can always use `.gitignore` to avoid tracking some file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content's still in the repo, that's what `git add` does, add content to the repo, but since you never committed wiping the index erased the only association with the right pathnames. Best you can do is

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

see its docs for what it does, basically look in `.git/lost-found/other` for the content you added and hopefully it won't be to hard to assign the right pathnames for each.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer.  I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222872/how-to-match-dangling-blobs-with-file-names-in-git after googling your response.  So this question is a duplicate we can  mark duplicate/delete.

To fix this issue I've just been renaming the blobs in .git/lost-found/other.  Fortunately I used one C# namespace which is within the files so I can easily find the files by searching the blob contents for DeltaSerach.